# f is continuous at a if and only if osc(f,a)=0

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

So I'm trying to prove this:
Let f:A-->R be bounded. Then f is continuous at a if and only if osc(f,a)=0.

I have the proof assuming f is continuous and showing osc(f,a)=0. However, I can't prove the converse, though I know it is similar.

Here's the first part:
Let f be continuous at a. For every number ϵ>0 we can choose a number δ>0 so that |f(x)-f(a)|<ϵ for all x∈A with |x-a|<δ. Thus M(a,f,δ)-m(a,f,δ)≤2ϵ, Since this is true for every ϵ,we have osc(f,a)=0.

Comment: Please define osc(f,a)-I'm not familiar with this terminology.

Comment: I'm not sure myself but I found something like it in a google book: https://books.google.com/books?id=sYNCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=osc%28f,a%29&source=bl&ots=r7wEPgaPoh&sig=zMUqoJpjw_jGUeprJXjBRV4Gtr4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZvPrVOGYB4PCggT144LIAg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=osc(f%2Ca)&f=false

Comment: I don't remember seeing that in Trench,but ok. Didn't read every page.

Comment: The oscillation osc(f,a) of f at a is defined by osc(f,a)=limit as δ approaches 0 of [M(a,f,δ)-m(a,f,δ)].

Comment: So $M$ and $m$ are the maximum and minimum values over $[a-\delta,a+\delta]$?

Answer (score 2):

To prove the converse of what you showed, suppose $osc(f,a)=0$.  Then given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta_0$ such that $\delta<\delta_0 \implies M(a,f,\delta)-m(a,f,\delta) < \epsilon$.  Then $|x-a|<\delta_0 \implies |f(a)-f(x)| < M(a,f,\delta)-m(a,f,\delta) < \epsilon$.